# Using typeconverters to convert List to Strings vice versa(Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I am having problems converting `Lists` -> `Strings` and 'Strings' to 'List' for type Converters in android studio.

**Entity**

```
data class Results(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
val id:Int? = null,

val category: List<String>,

val content: String?,

val country: List<String>?,

val creator: List<String>?,

val description: String?,

val image_url: String?,

val keywords: List<String>?,

val language: String?,

val link: String?,

val pubDate: String?,

val source_id: String?,

val title: String?,

val video_url: String?
)
```

**TypeConverter**

```
class Converters() {

    @TypeConverter
    fun listToJsonString(value: List<String>?): String? = Gson().toJson(value)

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonStringToList(value: String?) =
            Gson().fromJson(value, Array<String>::class.java).toList()
}
```

This is supposed to work however I got this error `Gson().fromJson(value, Array<String>::class.java) must not be null`, I assumed that I need to ensure the `value` parameter in `jsonStringToList` is not `null`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use `?.toList()`. Or if you want your class to be a bit easier to use with null safety, make the List properties of your entity non-nullable and use an empty list when applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Using Room 2.5.0 with the com.google.code.gson library 2.10.1 and core.ktx 1.9.0 your code compiles and runs.

e.g.

```
....
val r1 = Results(
            category = listOf(),
            content = "blah",
            country = listOf(),
            creator = listOf(),
            description = "blah",
            image_url = "nowhere",
            keywords = listOf(),
            language = "gibberish",
            link = "the link",
            pubDate = "2023-01-01",
            source_id = "somewhere",
            title = "This",
            video_url = ""
        )
        daoDB1.insert(r1)
        for (r in daoDB1.getAllResults()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Result is:- " +
                    "Content={${r.content}} " +
                    "Country=${r.country} " +
                    "Desc=${r.description} " +
                    "Img URL=${r.image_url} " +
                    "Lang=${r.language} " +
                    "Link= ${r.link} " +
                    "PubDate=${r.pubDate} " +
                    "Source=${r.source_id} " +
                    "Title=${r.title} " +
                    "VidURL=${r.video_url} " +
                    "#of Categories is ${r.category.size}" +
                    "#of Creators is ${r.creator!!.size} " +
                    "#of Keywords is ${r.keywords!!.size} " +
                    "")
        }
```

Results in:-

The Log containing:-

```
D/DBINFO: Result is:- Content={blah} Country=[] Desc=blah Img URL=nowhere Lang=gibberish Link= the link PubDate=2023-01-01 Source=somewhere Title=This VidURL= #of Categories is 0#of Creators is 0 #of Keywords is 0
```

and App Inspection showing:-

[image]

**BUT**

If you then specify a null instead of an empty list you will get a Null Pointer Exception when trying to extract the data.

e.g. if `country = listOf(),` is changed to `country = null,` then:-

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Gson().fromJson(value, Array<String>::class.java) must not be null
        at a.a.so75623951kotlinroommultipledifferentdatabases.Converters.jsonStringToList(DBStuff.kt:62)
        at a.a.so75623951kotlinroommultipledifferentdatabases.AllDao_Impl.getAllResults(AllDao_Impl.java:247)
        at a.a.so75623951kotlinroommultipledifferentdatabases.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:41)
```

Even though App Inspection shows that the row has been inserted successfully:-

[image]

- note 3rd row is due to running again without trying to extract as if there is an exception then the database is not available as the process is detached. i.e. row added just to allow App Inspection to see the database.

In short you should be saving an empty list and not allowing nulls otherwise using the TypeConverter results in an exception when it encounters the null. Thus you should always use `List<String>` not `List<String>?`.

- at least of using the com.google.code.gson library.